# Trying to write a jQuery function that shows content and hides the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a complicated (for me) function on my website. I had 3 rows, each containing an image. On hover I want this image background position to change, thats it. When the user then clicks this image, I want the parent div to expand in height, and the image to expand in height as well as change the background position of that.

After this function is complete and you click another image, Id like the previous one to scale back down to size, This is hard to explain so ive made a jsfiddle demo that I hope gives you all an idea.

Also as im new to jqwuery im a bit concerned my function looks bloated, is this bad practice or does it appear okay?

```
// On work showcase click, expand area to show information
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.work-showcase').animate({height:'135px'}, 500);
        $(this).find('ul li').animate({height:'350px'}, 500);
        $(this).find('ul li').css({
            'background-position':'bottom left',
            'background-size' : 'auto auto'
        });         
        $(this).find('ul li img').animate({height:'350px'}, 500);
        $(this).animate({height:'400px'}, 500,function() {  
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top });  
        });
    } else { return false;};
});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/mx4HJ/2/

Comment: can you share that jsfiddle? :-)

Comment: your demo seems to work fine (as you've described), am I missing something?

Comment: If you click one image @tborychowski the expand function works, then if you click another it works, but if you try and click a prior one it no longer opens, I understand this is because Ive added the class active, but im unsure how to remove it, or the best way, fi that makes sense?

Comment: I understand now, thanks. I've updated my answer with the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

One tip: always cache a jquery element if it's used more than once (e.g.

```
var el = $(this), li = el.find('ul li');
```

and for the other question, just edit this line where you add `active` class:

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mx4HJ/3/)

Comment: @mplungjan This is an answer for the question: "is this bad practice or does it appear okay?"

Comment: Thakns @tborychowski, Ill look into this :)